# Should i use null or integer to cast in the MySQL

Tags: mysql

```sql
with 
user_query as (select avg(cast(null as numeric)) as avg0,
                      sum(cast(null as numeric)) as sum0,
                      'd0e8e6fc-38d6-481c-8b1a-51ce688ea3fd' as columnId0,
                      'CHAR' as datatype0 
               from (select CountryCode,
                            District,
                            ID,
                            Name,
                            Population 
                     from world.city ) query ) 
select avg0 as alias_avg,
       sum0 as alias_sum,
       columnId0 as columnId,
       datatype0 as datatype 
from user_query;
```

Comment: `CAST(NULL AS NUMERIC)` isnt that equivalent to just `0` ? And why do you want to `SUM()` zeroes?

Comment: we will get empty values either it can any data type

Comment: I think this question can only be answered if you provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: (1) I cannot understand the logic. You select as many copies of the row with the values specified in CTE as is stored in `world.city` table... for what aim? (2) If you need the output column to contain NULL value and to have NUMERIC datatype then `CAST(NULL AS NUMERIC)` is correct solution.

Comment: @DanielW. *CAST(NULL AS NUMERIC) isnt that equivalent to just 0* No, of course.